# How can I align vertically/on top tikz pictures (circuitikz) in minipage/figure/tabular environment?

Tags: vertical-alignment, circuitikz, vertical-spacing

I am trying to align vertically this 3 circuits. I would like to align the on top, instead of bottom part (they automatically align bottom with that code).

Also, if possible, to know how to align the at the same 'pole' height. Thank you.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{tikz,circuitikz}
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=off]{caption}
\usepackage{float}


\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
 \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.0}
    \centering
    \Large
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}
    \scalebox{0.5}{
    \begin{circuitikz}[]
  \draw[]
  (0,3) to [R, l=$\mathbf{R_0}$,o-] (2,3) -- (2,4)
  to [C, l=$\mathbf{Q_{1}}$] (6,4) -- (6,3)
  to [short, -o] (7,3)
  (2,3) -- (2,2) to [R, l=$\mathbf{R_1}$] (6,2) -- (6,3); 
    \end{circuitikz}
    } & 
    \scalebox{0.5}{
     \begin{circuitikz}[]
  \draw[]
  (0,4) to [R, l=$R_0$,o-] (2,4) -- (2,5)
  to [C, l=$Q_{1}$] (8,5) -- (8,4)
  to [short, -o] (9,4)
  (2,4) -- (2,2) to [R, l=$R_1$] (4,2) -- (4,3)
  to [C, l=$Q_{2}$] (8,3)
  (4,2) -- (4,1) to [R, l=$R_2$] (8,1) -- (8,4); 
    \end{circuitikz}
    } & 
    \scalebox{0.5}{
    \begin{circuitikz}[]
  \draw[]
  (0,4) to [R, l=$R_0$,o-] (2,4) -- (2,5)
  to [C, l=$Q_{1}$] (9,5) -- (9,4)
  to [short, -o] (10,4)
  (2,4) -- (2,2) to [R, l=$R_1$] (4,2) -- (4,3)
  to [C, l=$Q_{2}$] (9,3)
  (4,2) -- (4,0) to [R, l=$R_2$] (6,0) -- (6,1)
  to [R, l=$R_3$] (9,1)
  (6,0) -- (6,-1) to [C, l=$Q_{3}$] (9,-1) -- (9,4); 
    \end{circuitikz}
    }\\ 
    \small(a) Randles & \small(b) 2 TC & \small(b) 3 TC
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\vspace{-3pt}    
\captionsetup{labelfont=bf,labelsep=period,font=small}
    \caption{description}
    \label{fig:circuits}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possibility is:

- for pictures define baseline: `baseline=(current bounding box.north)`
- use `tabularray` for table
- remove minipages

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{geometry} 
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage[skip=1ex,
            labelfont=bf,labelsep=period,font=small,
            singlelinecheck=off]{caption, subcaption}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
\tikzset{
    every picture/.append style = {baseline=(current bounding box.north), 
                                   scale=0.53, transform shape}
        }
\ctikzset{
    bipoles/capacitor/height=0.44,
    bipoles/capacitor/width=0.1,
        }
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {*{3}{Q[c]} }, 
             colsep  = 3pt,
             row{2}  = {font=\small, mode=math},
             row{3}  = {font=\small}
             }
    \begin{circuitikz}
\draw   (0,3) to [R, l=$\mathbf{R_0}$,o-] ++ (2,0) coordinate (aux)
              -- ++ (0, 1) 
              to [C, l=$\mathbf{Q_{1}}$]  ++ (2,0) -- ++ (0,-1)
              to [short, -o] ++ (1,0)
        (aux) -- ++ (0,-1) 
              to [R, l=$\mathbf{R_1}$]    ++ (2,0) -- ++ (0,1);
    \end{circuitikz}
    &   \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw   (0,4) to [R, l=$\mathbf{R_0}$,o-] ++ (2,0) coordinate (a)
                      -- ++ (0, 1)
                      to [C, l=$Q_{1}$]     ++ (4,0) -- ++ (0,-1)
                      to [short, -o] ++ (1,0)
                (a)   -- ++ (0,-1)
                      to [R, l=$R_1$]       ++ (2,0) coordinate (b)
                (b)   -- ++ (0, 1)
                      to [C, l=$Q_{2}$]     ++ (2,0)
                (b)   -- ++ (0,-1)
                      to [R, l=$R_2$]       ++ (2,0) -- ++ (0,2);
        \end{circuitikz}
    &   \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw   (0,5) to [R, l=$\mathbf{R_0}$,o-] ++ (2,0) coordinate (a)
                              -- ++ (0, 1)
                              to [C, l=$Q_{1}$]     ++ (6,0) -- ++ (0,-1)
                              to [short, -o] ++ (1,0)
                (a)   -- ++ (0,-1)
                      to [R, l=$R_1$]       ++ (2,0) coordinate (b)
                (b)   -- ++ (0, 1)
                      to [C, l=$Q_{2}$]     ++ (4,0)
                (b)   -- ++ (0,-1)
                      to [R, l=$R_2$]       ++ (2,0) coordinate (c)
                (c)   -- ++ (0, 1)
                      to [R, l=$R_3$]       ++ (2,0)
                (c)   -- ++ (0,-1)
                      to [C, l=$Q_{3}$]     ++ (2,0) -- ++ (0,3);
        \end{circuitikz}   \\
R(QR)       &   R(Q(R(QR))) &   R(Q(R(Q(R(QR)))))   \\
(a) Randles &   (b) 2 TC    &   (c) 3 TC
\end{tblr}
    \caption{Representación de los circuitos equivalentes modelados en este trabajo.}
    \label{fig:circuitos}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

Note:

- You may consider to increase text block by use of the `geometry` package and accordingly enlarge image scale value (for example at `\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}` to `scale=0.75`) and by this make scheme better readable:

[image]

- I took a liberty and redraw schemes with use of the relative coordinates. You may liked this way of drawing them.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. My knowledge about latex is still somewhat limited. I will give you the answer, I guess it is more efficient than mine (but I keep my answer since I prefer code I feel capable to deal with).

Comment: @AnibalMarrero, as you wish. However, now you have a unique opportunity to learn something new ... it may be very useful in the future projects.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I managed to solve it using the `minipage` environment command **\raisebox**.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{tikz,circuitikz}
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=off]{caption}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
 \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.0}
    \centering
    \Large
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}
    \raisebox{0.8\height}{\scalebox{0.5}{
    \begin{circuitikz}[]
  \draw[]
  (0,3) to [R, l=$\mathbf{R_0}$,o-] (2,3) -- (2,4)
  to [C, l=$\mathbf{Q_{1}}$] (6,4) -- (6,3)
  to [short, -o] (7,3)
  (2,3) -- (2,2) to [R, l=$\mathbf{R_1}$] (6,2) -- (6,3); 
    \end{circuitikz}
    }} & 
    \raisebox{0.14\height}{\scalebox{0.5}{
     \begin{circuitikz}[]
  \draw[]
  (0,4) to [R, l=$R_0$,o-] (2,4) -- (2,5)
  to [C, l=$Q_{1}$] (8,5) -- (8,4)
  to [short, -o] (9,4)
  (2,4) -- (2,2) to [R, l=$R_1$] (4,2) -- (4,3)
  to [C, l=$Q_{2}$] (8,3)
  (4,2) -- (4,1) to [R, l=$R_2$] (8,1) -- (8,4); 
    \end{circuitikz}
    }} & 
    \raisebox{-0.19\height}{\scalebox{0.5}{
    \begin{circuitikz}[]
  \draw[]
  (0,4) to [R, l=$R_0$,o-] (2,4) -- (2,5)
  to [C, l=$Q_{1}$] (9,5) -- (9,4)
  to [short, -o] (10,4)
  (2,4) -- (2,2) to [R, l=$R_1$] (4,2) -- (4,3)
  to [C, l=$Q_{2}$] (9,3)
  (4,2) -- (4,0) to [R, l=$R_2$] (6,0) -- (6,1)
  to [R, l=$R_3$] (9,1)
  (6,0) -- (6,-1) to [C, l=$Q_{3}$] (9,-1) -- (9,4); 
    \end{circuitikz}
    }}\\ 
    \small$R(QR)$ & \small$R(Q(R(QR)))$ & \small$R(Q(R(Q(R(QR)))))$ \\
    \small(a) Randles & \small(b) 2 TC & \small(c) 3 TC
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\vspace{-3pt}    
\captionsetup{labelfont=bf,labelsep=period,font=small}
    \caption{Representación de los circuitos equivalentes modelados en este trabajo.}
    \label{fig:circuitos}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Another options/solutions/advises will be apreciated anyway. I hope my answer will be useful anyway.